# Micronaut access application.yml with @Value

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

Hello i have a micronaut application with this application.yml

```
micronaut:
    application:
        name: hello-world
pref:
    msg: Luca
```

inside a class i want to set the value of a variable :

```
@Value("${pref.msg}")
private lateinit var text : String
```

but the IDE complains saying that annotation argument must be a compile time constants

i also tried with

```
@Property(name = "pref.msg" )
```

but it compiles but do not read the property.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape `$` char using a backslash, because dollar is used by kotlin for template espressions.

```
@Value("\${pref.msg}")
```